# How to find Only the logged in user content in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
        return '@{}'.format(self.username)



class placement(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    ad_space=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    PID_TYPE = (
        ('FN','FORMAT_NATIVE'),
        ('FNB','FORMAT_NATIVE_BANNER'),
        ('FI','FORMAT_INTERSTITIAL'),
        ('FB','FORMAT_BANNER'),
        ('FMR','FORMAT_MEDIUM,RECT'),
        ('FRV','FORMAT_REWARDED_VIDEO'),
    )

    format = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices = PID_TYPE,default = 'FN',blank=False, null=False)
    pid=models.CharField( max_length=50,default='',blank=False, null=False)
    cpm=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False, null=False)
    ADS_TYPE=(
        ('FB','FACEBOOK'),
        ('G','GOOGLE'),
    )

    source=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=ADS_TYPE,default='FB',blank=False, null=False)
    comments=models.TextField(default='',blank=False, null=False)
    objects=models.Manager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("dashapp:disp")`
```

Now what should i do to only get only the logged in user content to be displayed on the template.As currently all the stored data is being fetched . That is logged out user for data is being displayed.
I'm Basically a beginner so i dont have any advance idea about this.
Full explanation are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the logged in user like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

In django, the logged in user has an attribute `is_authenticated` which is a boolean value. If user is logged in, it gives `True`, else `False`.

### Update

If you meant to see the `placement` model values in template for current user, you need make some relations with the user to `placement`. So you need to update the placement model:

```
class placement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=None)
    ....  # rest of the fields
```

And save user info to placement in views:

```
class SomeCreateView(CreateView):
   ...
   def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = User.objects.get(id = self.request.user.id)
        return super(SomeCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and get placements of a user in view like this:

```
 placements = placement.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: No I'm asking for to display only that data  (from model content) which is saved by the current logged in user. If you have any Idea or way that'd be of great help

Comment: How can i connect to you. AS i have few other issues and i think you'd be of great help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. Please accept this answer if it helped you. And if you have other issues, please post questions in SO, we would be happy to help

Comment: I'm having trouble of saving this data . As not getting any clue where to store `placement.user=request.user`                                                           `placement.save()`        ADDING my VIews here . Help me here .                              `class createPlace(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    fields=('name','ad_space','format','pid','cpm','source','comments')
    model=placement
    template_name='createpl.html'` This is the View from which i'm saving my model data to Database

Comment: How should i Implement your steps??

Comment: I have updated my view with an example code. Hope it helps

Comment: I know I'm asking too much but can you explain me few things as a go through the updated code . such as PlacementForm

Comment: Well, its a [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) :). Its just an example on how you can write a view and update it with current user.

Comment: So I have to create a Modelform inside my model class ??

Comment: @AnoopSharma how do you create the `placement` instances?

Comment: I used CreateView to handle my model and then template to handle the form . Thats how my data was being stored in database. I have sent you the view above .Please take a look.

Comment: Ah, that makes things easier. I have updated the view

Comment: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: XXXX>>": "placement.user" must be a "User" instance.                                                                                                     I'm getting this error On adding your above form method

Comment: Now the error that popped up is `name 'User' is not defined`.

Comment: please import the `User` model

Comment: I'm Literally stuck in this issue.Being a newbie I'm having issue understanding internet help for this problem. The new error on writing down your above update form code                                                                       `def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = User.objects.get(id = self.request.user.id)
        return super(SomeCreateView, self).form_valid(form)`                            I'm getting new error  as `name 'User' is not defined`

Comment: well, you need to import the User model which you have defined in the question

Comment: `Exception Value:`          

`User matching query does not exist.`                                                                              Now I'm getting this exception . It'd be great if i connect to you in someway.

Comment: what is your Auth Model? if its django's own, then don't use the model code you have provided with your question. And I have updated the answer in both model and view. Please have a look

Comment: Yes I'm using django's own auth .I'm using your only `def form_valid` method .But its giving me the above mentioned error. Is there any way i Send you the entire code to have a look at??

Comment: maybe its best if you can ask another question with full model view and error. :)